# ElasticSearch with Docker: how to persist data with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to run ElasticSearch on Docker (actually on AWS ECS). If I don't configure the volume it's working correctly, but every time I restart the container I lose all the data. 
I can't figure out how to configure the volume.

**What I tried:**

1. in the task definition I configured volume "Name=esdata1" and "source path=/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
2. inside the container definition in the "storage and logging" section I configured the mount point "source volume= esdata1" and "container path=/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"

Now when I launch the container it fail with error "access denied" when elasticsearch try to write in "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data". So in the section Security I configured "user=ec2-user" but then the container will not even launch (stay in "status=created"). What should I do? I guess the issue is due to the fact that the user of the container must be the same of the one on the host. The user on the host is "ec2-user", I don't know how to proceed.

**Edit:**

I'm now able to persist data with this configuration:
[image]
[image]

```
docker inspect:

"Mounts": [
            {
                "Name": "elasticsearch_data",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/elasticsearch_data/_data",
                "Destination": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ]
```

Now data persist if I stop the container or I reboot the host. My only last concern is that this folder "/var/lib/docker/volumes/elasticsearch_data/_data" is located on the OS volume and not on the bigger docker volume. From [Aws doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html):

> Amazon ECS-optimized AMIs from version 2015.09.d and later launch with
>   an 8 GiB volume for the operating system that is attached at /dev/xvda
>   and mounted as the root of the file system. There is an additional 22
>   GiB volume that is attached at /dev/xvdcz that Docker uses for image
>   and metadata storage. The volume is configured as a Logical Volume
>   Management (LVM) device and it is accessed directly by Docker via the
>   devicemapper back end.

How can I persist data on /dev/xvdcz?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sourcepath is the path on the host instance where the data is written. In your case `elasticsearch_data`. You need to point sourcepath to a folder that exists and that is on the disk you want on the EC2 instance.

So attach an EBS disk to the instance. Mount the disk in a place like `/data/es` and set your source path to that folder.

But remember that to properly run ES you would probably need a cluster of machines that are connected and automated backups. Consider using the managed ES from Amazon if you plan to host critical data. It does not sound like you have a very robust setup here.

Comment: Thanks very much: 
1. I'm sorry I think it's a very dumb question, but "attach an EBS disk to the instance. Mount the disk" is really what I'm missing: shouldn't be that disk already mounted? (according to the AWS docs)
2. the managed ES from AWS is quite old, I can't use it since they update it less than once a year.
3. The setup is really not robust, I'm actually here to learn. I'm aware I need a cluster, that's the reason I was thinking about using ECS in order to easily launch a cluster of nodes.

Comment: @StefanoGiacone I would not recommend using the disk with the docker containers on. You need a clean disk that only contains the ES data. 
If you use Launch Configuration to create instances you can add another disk there. Then in the User Data script in the launch config you mount the disk and format it.

Or you can add the disk manually to the instance. I don't know how automated and self recovering you want this setup.

But you should create a new EBS for only the ES storage. This will make backup and so on easier.

Comment: I guess that's a good approach, I think I'll go for it. Regarding backups: do you believe are useful? I believe that ES replication do a better job

Comment: @StefanoGiacone It is just so easy to take a snapshot of an entire EBS volumne that I don't see why not. Of course the replication will help a long way. But you never know when a snapshot of a EBS might come in handy.

Comment: @StefanoGiacone AWS now supports ElasticSearch 5: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/01/elasticsearch-5-now-available-on-amazon-elasticsearch-service/